# Print alternate number representations in pdb

Tags: python, pdb

I've got a value (call it address) which is a memory address and I am trying to figure out where it is pointing.

```
(pdb) p address
18446738026812173208L
```

With the help of a hex converter, I can find out that this is equal to `0x0AFEBFB4`, but how do I force hex-formatted output from the debugger itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `hex`, `oct`, `bin` and `int` functions:

```
In [8]: hex(18446738026812173208L)
Out[8]: '0xfffffa8018d46b98L'

In [9]: oct(18446738026812173208L)
Out[9]: '01777777650003065065630L'

In [10]: bin(18446738026812173208L)
Out[10]: '0b1111111111111111111110101000000000011000110101000110101110011000'

In [11]: int(bin(18446738026812173208L), 2)
Out[11]: 18446738026812173208L

In [12]: int(oct(18446738026812173208)[:-1], 8)
Out[12]: 18446738026812173208L

In [13]: int(hex(18446738026812173208)[:-1], 16)
Out[13]: 18446738026812173208L
```

The slicing is required as all three functions return a string and both `oct` and `hex` append `L`.